# Define function() outside useEffect() will cause net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not have any problem to defined a function() outside useEffect() on other pages of my React Web App. However, only one api call will cause me net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES. The data on this page will return and display to the data table, but it will keep sending the request and network status is pending. If I define the function inside useEffect(), it will not cause any problem.

The reason I define the function outside useEffect() is because if I add new data, the table on this page will update without reload the browser.

```
   const initDataFunction = async () => {
    try {
      const filter = {
        include: {
          relation: 'something1',
          scope: {
            include: {
              relation: 'something2',
            },
          },
        },
      };
      const data1 = await getDataById(id, filter);
      setData(data1);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initDataFunction();
  }, []);

  export const getDataById = async (id, filter = {}) => {
  const token = Storage.accessToken.get();

  return (
    await await Api.get(`/data1/${id}`, {
      params: {
        access_token: token,
        filter,
      },
    })
  ).data;
};
```

If I defined the initDataFunction() inside useEffect(), can I still get the data table on this page update without reload the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Update!
Maybe because of the api call multiple relations so it return Infinite Loop inside useEffect(). This is how I fixed the problem.

```
   const initDataFunction = async () => {
     //get Data .... 
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    const initData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await initDataFunction();
      setLoading(false);
    };
    initData();
  }, []);
```